# Regular expression to capture word withing double quotes

Tags: regex, ant

I am trying to extract word between double quotes and it works fine for me but if line has extra attribute then it fails.

Line:

```
sca:property xmi:id="_P1Nw8fUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC"
```

I want to extract value of scaext:simpleValue, meaning "DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" shoudl be output.

I used : `(.*)(scaext:simpleValue=)(.*)` and it works fine.

But sometime line can be

```
sca:property xmi:id="_P5X4MvUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"
```

In this case my regular expression does not work and output also contains source="$solutionDB"...

I want expected output to be : `DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC`

Please can anyone help me to get this right to extract just value of scaext:simpleValue tag.

I am using it in Apache ant script.

Comment: Are you replacing with Group 3?  Try `.*scaext:simpleValue="([^"]+).*`. Else, remove the `.*` on both ends and grab `\1`.

Comment: I used below line in ant script   <propertyregex property="RTName" override="true" input="${RTNameTemp}" regexp="scaext:simpleValue="([^"]+)" select="\1"/>  where input is <sca:property xmi:id="_dEriYfYKEeeNrJ1fB1BovA" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"/>  but then ant script fails to parse command and throws error Element type "propertyregex" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"...I believe it complains on double quotes in between which breaks syntax

Comment: Yes, the `"` must be changed to `\"`

Comment: Hi wiktor..Your answer actually gave me right way..i just posted solution...now it works for me in ant script as well...Thanks for help.

Comment: HI Wiktor...I did used \" as in regexp="([^\"]+)"  but still in ant it gives sytax error as said above..So i had to use (ampersandsignquote;) where ampersand sign is = & ...now it resolves correctly

Comment: Ok, perhaps, you are using it in the XML? Then you need to use `&quot;` instead of `"`.

Comment: Yes its used in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a non-greedy operator so you can couple `?` to make it stop on the first match, in that case, the `"` that surrounds the word offers the perfect "greed stop":

try `scaext:simpleValue="(.+?)"` to retrieve just what is in between quotes for `simpleValue` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/UgabMp/1/)

[More info here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in Ant. It's usually good to avoid ant-contrib whenever possible (note: it's almost always possible).

```
<target name="replace">
    <property name="input1" value='sca:property xmi:id="_P1Nw8fUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC"' />
    <property name="input2" value='sca:property xmi:id="_P5X4MvUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"' />

    <property name="pattern" value=".*scaext:simpleValue=&quot;(.+?)&quot;.*" />
    <property name="replace" value="\1" />

    <loadresource property="result1">
        <propertyresource name="input1" />
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="${pattern}" replace="${replace}" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadresource>

    <loadresource property="result2">
        <propertyresource name="input2" />
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="${pattern}" replace="${replace}" />
            </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>

    <echo message="${result1}" />
    <echo message="${result2}" />
</target>
```

With a `macrodef` for convenience:

```
<target name="replace">
    <property name="input1" value='sca:property xmi:id="_P1Nw8fUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC"' />
    <property name="input2" value='sca:property xmi:id="_P5X4MvUZEeeA4MWHFtA5gw" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"' />

    <property name="pattern" value=".*scaext:simpleValue=&quot;(.+?)&quot;.*" />
    <property name="replace" value="\1" />

    <replaceregex
        property="result1"
        input="input1"
        pattern="${pattern}"
        replace="${replace}"
    />

    <replaceregex
        property="result2"
        input="input2"
        pattern="${pattern}"
        replace="${replace}"
    />

    <echo message="${result1}" />
    <echo message="${result2}" />
</target>

<macrodef name="replaceregex">
    <attribute name="property" />
    <attribute name="input" />
    <attribute name="pattern" />
    <attribute name="replace" />
    <sequential>
        <loadresource property="@{property}">
            <propertyresource name="@{input}" />
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="@{pattern}" replace="@{replace}" />
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found way to deal with my problem .
In ant script i used below

Lets say ,

Input string , RTNameTemp = sca:property xmi:id="_dEriYfYKEeeNrJ1fB1BovA" mustSupply="false" name="SolutionDB" type="jdbc:JdbcDataSource" scaext:simpleValue="DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"/

Then in ant script

1) First i used 
propertyregex property="RTNamewithQuotes" override="true" input="${RTNameTemp}" regexp="(.*)(scaext:simpleValue=)(.*)(/)" select="\3" />

It will extract all lines after "scaext:simpleValue=" ie output will be 
"DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC" source="$SolutionDB"

After this i stored this output in a property , then used,

propertyregex property="RTName" override="true" input="${RTNamewithQuotes}" regexp="([^(")]+)" select="\1"/>

So outcome is : DealAmendmentsSolutionJDBC

Actually solutions which you all gave works perfectly but very importantly it should fit with apache ant script ( in my case).
I took answer from Wiktor to use ([^"]+) , only thing i modified is , i replaced actual " with (ampersandsignquot;) which resolves to (") ..so now it is readable in apache ant script.

Thanks guys for help.